# Show each ball after 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created some balls using the following code :

```
function game() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var ball = $("<div>");
        ball.prop("class","planets");
        ball.prop("id","planet"+i);
        $("body").append(ball);
    }
}

function showing() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            $("#planet" + i).toggle();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.planets {
    display: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="game()">Play</button>
<button onclick="showing()">Show</button>
```

Now my question. I want to create a function that will make each ball visible after 1 sec. I have created the function `showing()` but it will make all balls visible at once. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your `showing()` function to the question.

Comment: Sorry.added showing() code

Comment: please, show us the showing() function code, if that is the one you have the issue in.

Comment: You don't seem to `var i;`

Answer (score 2):

Adding a timer to showing after each new ball:

```
   function game() {
        var timer = 1000;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var ball = $("<div>");
            ball.prop("class","planets");
            ball.prop("id","planet"+i);
            $("body").append(ball);
            setTimeout(function() {
                ball.show();
            }, timer * (i+1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setTimeout` function:

```
setTimeout(showing, 1000);
```

The first argument is a function that should be executed and the second argument is the number of milliseconds to wait before executing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setInterval` function:

```
interval = setInterval(showing, 1000);

var i = 0;
function showing() {
  $("#planet" + i++).show();
  //however many ball you have
  if(i == 3)
  {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
```

Very similar to `setTimeout` except it runs repeatedly until you tell it to stop; the first argument is the function and the second is the number of mmilliseconds bewtween each iteration (1000 milliseconds = 1 second)

When you want the interval to stop, you call `clearInterval`:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show a new ball 1 second after a click on the Show button.

```
function showing() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.planets:hidden').eq(0).show();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I have to press the button to show each ball.I want when i press the button after 1 second to sho one ball till i have shown them all

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to your needs.